# How to store zero in a char array instead of it storing null [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, char

Apologies for the possibly poorly written question and lack of knowledge.

Im trying to store the actual character "0" in an array but it keeps defaulting to null. Is there anyway to avoid this?
Below is a modified version of my code. I am trying to compare two binary numbers and then when the numbers dont match, the following numbers become all zeroes. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
        String fullBinOne = "1010101010100101"
        String fullBinTwo = "1010101010101010"
        char[] charBinOne = fullBinOne.toCharArray();
        char[] charBinTwo = fullBinTwo.toCharArray();
        char[] routeSummaryArray = fullBinOne.toCharArray();

        int subnetCIDR = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < charBinOne.length; i++){
            if (charBinOne[i] != charBinTwo[i]) {
                subnetCIDR = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = subnetCIDR; i < charBinOne.length; i++){
            routeSummaryArray[i] = (char)0;
        }
```

The output of routeSummaryArray is "101010101010    "
instead of being                    1010101010100000

Comment: The character `0` is indicated by `'0'`, not by `(char) 0`.

Comment: How do you output `routeSummaryArray`?

Comment: routeSummaryArray[i] = '0';

Answer (score 1):

```
routeSummaryArray[i] = (char)0;
```

(char)0 is typecasting the integer value(here 0) to character. Here, the **ASCII value of the integer value** (here 0) will be stored to the specified index of the character array named "routeSummaryArray".

**ASCII value of 0 is *null***. So it outputs as "101010101010".

If you need output as 1010101010100000, either use

```
routeSummaryArray[i] = '0';
```

or,

```
routeSummaryArray[i] = (char)48;
```

**'0' is the ASCII value of 48".**

For your reference, http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: But more importantly, character `'0'` has a UNICODE value of 48.